# Load datatable from html-dom and on action make server-side ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Basically I have a page that just have a server-side ajax based datatable.
The ajax takes few seconds to load the data and the page is useless until then.

I think this takes 2 round http trips, one for page call and one for ajax.
If I load the datatable from dom for initial request then how can I make it to user server-side ajax on interaction (next, search, sort etc.)

I assume this approach is better and fast in my opinion but I don't know how to achieve this, if I should.

Comment: probably they could have docs about it, have you done any research?

Comment: @Jai I did looked into the docs, but I didn't found use case related to mine. I'm looking into solutions meanwhile

Comment: Is there some other way you could improve the datatable loading time? e.g. the query? What else is on the page other than the datatable?

Comment: It seems there is no built-in way to do as I need. I'll have to stick with ajax request on page load I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
deferRender: true
```

to your DataTable options. This way, DataTable will create the table the moment it has the number of your displayLength and not wait for all your data to be retrieved.

See Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender

Comment: I have already used this option. Its not what I was looking for. But It does help rendering faster. I'll stick with default ajax behavior.